# Comparing image searching with AHK or pyAutoGUI?

Tags: python, autohotkey, pyautogui

I am considering UI automation.

image searching of pyAutoGUI (Python) seems a little slow comparing with Autohotkey.

I guess pyautoGUI try to find image from full screen
but autohotkey try to find image from specific area
because I use "winactive" option.

Can anyone give a advice?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you are using Windows)

AutoHotkey/AHK is much better option here,
as it does not rely on dependency like python does and performs better, even with minimal resources.

> specific area because I use "winactive" option

It doesn't have to, you can search whole screen..[[ImageSearch AHK Docs]](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm)

example.,

```
IMG_PATH := "‪C:\Users\YOURNAME\Desktop\gLogo.bmp"
CoordMode Pixel  ; Interprets the coordinates below as relative to the screen rather than the active window.
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, *50 %IMG_PATH%
if (ErrorLevel = 2)
    MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
else if (ErrorLevel = 1)
    MsgBox Icon could not be found on the screen.
else
    MouseMove, %FoundX%,%FoundY%
```

It doesn't have to be a **.bmp** you can use any image with least-compression.

After all compared to pyautogui, AHK is much simpler to write.